# how to use Windows VM system-assigned managed identity to access sql server installed on that VM

Tags: azure-active-directory, active-directory-group

I have a SQL server installed in Azure VM. VM is having managed identity. I want to connect to SQL server using that managed identity. How can I achieve this

Comment: It may be worth rephrasing your question.  To be clear, Azure Active Directory and Azure Active Directory Domain Services are not the same offering.  If you have both Azure Active Directory and a connected Azure Active Directory Domain Services provisioned with users, you can domain join a SQL Server virtual machine to the AADDS domain and add users (or groups) from the AADDS domain to SQL Server Logins.  Since the Virtual Machine Identity is basically a managed service account you won't be able to login with it. In theory you can connect a different managed ID, that's what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot.
MSI is only an option for Azure SQL DB. Not for SQL Server installed on VM.

Check the `Important` notice here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication-configure

Comment: Thanks staykov, the article says Connecting to SQL Server running on an Azure VM is not supported using an Azure Active Directory account. Use a domain Active Directory account instead.
I wanted to know how can I use domain Active directory account to login in SQL server.

Comment: please be morr in your question what exactly are you trying to achieve.

Comment: I am trying to connect a SQL Server inside a Azure VM and want to use Azure Active directory domain account.